# Access property of an object that is a Map value

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a Map:

`Map<String, Order> activeOrders = { // ... already some values inside ... }`

with keys(order IDs) as *Strings* and values as custom *Order* objects defined as:

```
// custom object used as Map values
Order(
  String name;
  List<OrderItem> orderItems;
)
```

I need a function that takes order ID (used as key in the *Map*) and item as parameters, searches for a particular key/value pair of *activeOrders* Map with given *orderId* as a key, and adds given item to the list of *orderItems* of an *Order* object at that key value.

How can I access orderItems list property of an Order object and call *add* method on the list to append the new item?

```
void addItem(String orderId, OrderItem item) {
   // add item to orderItems property of a Map value at the itemId key
}
```

I tried creating a brand new Order object inside function, therefor replacing already existing object value, but creating new object every time is not what I want. Goal is to modify an existing objects property by appeding new item to its list property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of creating classes, to get named parameters but you could use

```
({String name, List<OrderItem> orderItems})
```

if you don't want a class.

```
class Order {
   final String name;
   final List<OrderItem> orderItems;

   const Order(this.name, this.orderItems);
}

class OrderItem {
   const OrderItem();
}


main() {

   Map<String, Order> activeOrders = {'myKey': Order('myOtherKey', List<OrderItem>.empty(growable: true))};

   void addItem(String orderId, OrderItem item) {
      activeOrders.update(orderId, (value) => value..orderItems.add(item));
   }

   print(activeOrders['myKey']?.orderItems);

   addItem('myKey', OrderItem());
   print(activeOrders['myKey']?.orderItems);
}
```

Note that the list created must be growable in order to add items.